# Overlaying points on a ggmap

Tags: plot, points, ggmap

So I'm putting trees in forest plots into a map of Madagascar
The beginning on the data set looks like this:

```
#ggmap!
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)
map <- get_map(location = 'Madagascar', zoom = 4)
ggmap(map)
map <- get_map(location = 'Madagascar', zoom = 10)
geocode("kianjavato")
#lon       lat
#47.86682 -21.38024
k <- "kianjavato"
#qmap(k, zoom = 16)
#qmap(k, zoom = 16, source = "stamen", maptype = "toner")
myMap <- get_map(location=k, source="stamen", maptype="toner", crop=FALSE, zoom=16)
# having trouble zooming
ggmap(myMap)
```

Here is the code I use to make the map and get the points:

```
ggplot(data=GPScorrect,aes(x=Lon,y=Lat))+geom_point()
```

But when I go to plot the two together using this code:

```
ggmap(myMap) + geom_point(data=GPScorrect,aes(x = 'Lon', y ='Lat'))
```

I get this error message:

```
Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale
```

PLEASE HELP

Answer (score 0):

When asking questions, be sure to provide a working example that executes front to back until it encounters the error you're asking about. In this case, you don't supply data for `GPScorrect`.

Un-quote your aesthetic mappings. If you re-work the following stripped down example you should get what you're looking for:

```
library(ggmap)
library(mapproj)
myMap <- get_map(location = 'Madagascar', zoom = 6)

e1 <- geocode('Antananarivo')
e2 <- geocode('Toamasina')
e3 <- geocode('Antsirabe')
GPScorrect <- rbind(e1, e2, e3)

ggmap(myMap) + geom_point(data=GPScorrect,aes(x = lon, y =lat), color = 'firebrick', size = 3)
```